# OPENAM - Domain not found at Login.jsp

Tags: single-sign-on, openam, opensso

We are implementing a distAuth and happen some problems, when we try access https://login.example.com/distAuth, in the top of page we get "Please wait while redirecting..." and the page goes BLANK, some time after "Domain invalid.jsp" apear... the domaind invalid.jsp is in the same server of Login.jsp, but we cant get the login page, we try hard for 4 days and nothing, please someone can help?:

The logs:

CoreSystem

```
amJAXRPC:07/25/2013 10:05:48:417 AM BRT: Thread[WebContainer : 0,5,main]
SOAP Client: READ Exception
java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 500 for URL: https://ssoweb.intranet.bb.com.br:443/sso/jaxrpc/SMSObjectIF
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1448)
        at com.ibm.net.ssl.www2.protocol.https.b.getInputStream(b.java:50)
        at com.sun.identity.shared.jaxrpc.SOAPClient.call(SOAPClient.java:244)
        at com.sun.identity.shared.jaxrpc.SOAPClient.send(SOAPClient.java:326)
        at com.sun.identity.shared.jaxrpc.SOAPClient.send(SOAPClient.java:312)
        at com.sun.identity.shared.jaxrpc.JAXRPCHelper.isServerValid(JAXRPCHelper.java:153)
        at com.sun.identity.shared.jaxrpc.JAXRPCHelper.getValidServerURL(JAXRPCHelper.java:134)
        at com.sun.identity.shared.jaxrpc.JAXRPCHelper.getValidURL(JAXRPCHelper.java:74)
        at com.sun.identity.shared.jaxrpc.SOAPClient.call(SOAPClient.java:174)
        at com.sun.identity.shared.jaxrpc.SOAPClient.send(SOAPClient.java:326)
        at com.sun.identity.shared.jaxrpc.SOAPClient.send(SOAPClient.java:312)
        at com.iplanet.am.sdk.remote.RemoteServicesImpl.getSearchFilterFromTemplate(RemoteServicesImpl.java:1716)
        at com.iplanet.am.sdk.AMSearchFilterManager.getSearchFilter(AMSearchFilterManager.java:122)
        at com.iplanet.am.sdk.AMStoreConnection.getOrganizationDN(AMStoreConnection.java:667)
        at com.sun.identity.idm.IdUtils.getOrganization(IdUtils.java:503)
        at com.sun.identity.authentication.client.AuthClientUtils.getOrganizationDN(AuthClientUtils.java:1460)
        at com.sun.identity.authentication.client.AuthClientUtils.getDomainNameByRequest(AuthClientUtils.java:1540)
        at com.sun.identity.authentication.distUI.LoginViewBean.forwardTo(LoginViewBean.java:309)
        at com.iplanet.jato.ApplicationServletBase.dispatchRequest(ApplicationServletBase.java:981)
        at com.iplanet.jato.ApplicationServletBase.processRequest(ApplicationServletBase.java:615)
        at com.iplanet.jato.ApplicationServletBase.doGet(ApplicationServletBase.java:459)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:718)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:831)
        at com.ibm.ws.cache.servlet.ServletWrapper.serviceProxied(ServletWrapper.java:307)
        at com.ibm.ws.cache.servlet.CacheHook.handleFragment(CacheHook.java:576)
        at com.ibm.ws.cache.servlet.CacheHook.handleServlet(CacheHook.java:250)
        at com.ibm.ws.cache.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:259)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1657)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1597)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:131)
        at com.sun.identity.distauth.setup.DistAuthConfiguratorFilter.doFilter(DistAuthConfiguratorFilter.java:101)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:188)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:116)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain._doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:77)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.doFilter(WebAppFilterManager.java:908)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:934)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:502)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapperImpl.handleRequest(ServletWrapperImpl.java:181)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.CacheServletWrapper.handleRequest(CacheServletWrapper.java:91)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java:864)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.handleRequest(WSWebContainer.java:1592)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.channel.WCChannelLink.ready(WCChannelLink.java:186)
        at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleDiscrimination(HttpInboundLink.java:452)
        at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleNewRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:511)
        at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.processRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:305)
        at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpICLReadCallback.complete(HttpICLReadCallback.java:83)
        at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.AioReadCompletionListener.futureCompleted(AioReadCompletionListener.java:165)
        at com.ibm.io.async.AbstractAsyncFuture.invokeCallback(AbstractAsyncFuture.java:217)
        at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncChannelFuture.fireCompletionActions(AsyncChannelFuture.java:161)
        at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncFuture.completed(AsyncFuture.java:138)
        at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.complete(ResultHandler.java:204)
        at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.runEventProcessingLoop(ResultHandler.java:775)
        at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler$2.run(ResultHandler.java:905)
        at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1646)

amJAXRPC:07/25/2013 10:05:47:381 AM BRT: Thread[WebContainer : 0,5,main]
WARNING: JAXRPCHelper: No vaild server found

IdRepo

amProfile_Client:07/25/2013 10:06:06:261 AM BRT: Thread[WebContainer : 0,5,main]
ERROR: RemoteServicesImpl.getNamingAttr: caught exception=
java.rmi.RemoteException: no-server-found
        at com.sun.identity.shared.jaxrpc.SOAPClient.call(SOAPClient.java:189)
        at com.sun.identity.shared.jaxrpc.SOAPClient.send(SOAPClient.java:326)
        at com.sun.identity.shared.jaxrpc.SOAPClient.send(SOAPClient.java:312)
        at com.iplanet.am.sdk.remote.RemoteServicesImpl.getNamingAttribute(RemoteServicesImpl.java:1625)
        at com.iplanet.am.sdk.AMNamingAttrManager.getNamingAttr(AMNamingAttrManager.java:68)
        at com.iplanet.am.sdk.AMNamingAttrManager.getNamingAttr(AMNamingAttrManager.java:52)
        at com.iplanet.am.sdk.AMStoreConnection.orgNameToDN(AMStoreConnection.java:1831)
        at com.iplanet.am.sdk.AMStoreConnection.getOrganizationDN(AMStoreConnection.java:629)
        at com.sun.identity.idm.IdUtils.getOrganization(IdUtils.java:503)
        at com.sun.identity.authentication.client.AuthClientUtils.getOrganizationDN(AuthClientUtils.java:1485)
        at com.sun.identity.authentication.client.AuthClientUtils.getDomainNameByRequest(AuthClientUtils.java:1540)
        at com.sun.identity.authentication.distUI.LoginViewBean.forwardTo(LoginViewBean.java:309)
        at com.iplanet.jato.ApplicationServletBase.dispatchRequest(ApplicationServletBase.java:981)
        at com.iplanet.jato.ApplicationServletBase.processRequest(ApplicationServletBase.java:615)
        at com.iplanet.jato.ApplicationServletBase.doGet(ApplicationServletBase.java:459)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:718)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:831)
        at com.ibm.ws.cache.servlet.ServletWrapper.serviceProxied(ServletWrapper.java:307)
        at com.ibm.ws.cache.servlet.CacheHook.handleFragment(CacheHook.java:576)
        at com.ibm.ws.cache.servlet.CacheHook.handleServlet(CacheHook.java:250)
        at com.ibm.ws.cache.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:259)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1657)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1597)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:131)
        at com.sun.identity.distauth.setup.DistAuthConfiguratorFilter.doFilter(DistAuthConfiguratorFilter.java:101)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:188)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:116)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain._doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:77)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.doFilter(WebAppFilterManager.java:908)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:934)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:502)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapperImpl.handleRequest(ServletWrapperImpl.java:181)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.CacheServletWrapper.handleRequest(CacheServletWrapper.java:91)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java:864)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.handleRequest(WSWebContainer.java:1592)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.channel.WCChannelLink.ready(WCChannelLink.java:186)
        at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleDiscrimination(HttpInboundLink.java:452)
        at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleNewRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:511)
        at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.processRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:305)
        at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpICLReadCallback.complete(HttpICLReadCallback.java:83)
        at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.AioReadCompletionListener.futureCompleted(AioReadCompletionListener.java:165)
        at com.ibm.io.async.AbstractAsyncFuture.invokeCallback(AbstractAsyncFuture.java:217)
        at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncChannelFuture.fireCompletionActions(AsyncChannelFuture.java:161)
        at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncFuture.completed(AsyncFuture.java:138)
        at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.complete(ResultHandler.java:204)
        at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.runEventProcessingLoop(ResultHandler.java:775)
        at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler$2.run(ResultHandler.java:905)
        at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1646)




Configuration

amSMS:07/25/2013 10:06:22:217 AM BRT: Thread[WebContainer : 0,5,main]
ERROR: ServiceManager::isRealmEnabled unable to initialize
SMSException Exception Code:5
Message:An registered exception occurred.  Please see log for further details.
--------------------------------------------------
The lower level exception message
no-server-found
The lower level exception:
java.rmi.RemoteException: no-server-found
        at com.sun.identity.shared.jaxrpc.SOAPClient.call(SOAPClient.java:189)
        at com.sun.identity.shared.jaxrpc.SOAPClient.send(SOAPClient.java:326)
        at com.sun.identity.shared.jaxrpc.SOAPClient.send(SOAPClient.java:312)
        at com.sun.identity.sm.jaxrpc.SMSJAXRPCObject.read(SMSJAXRPCObject.java:115)
        at com.sun.identity.sm.SMSEntry.read(SMSEntry.java:698)
        at com.sun.identity.sm.SMSEntry.read(SMSEntry.java:675)
        at com.sun.identity.sm.SMSEntry.<init>(SMSEntry.java:469)
        at com.sun.identity.sm.CachedSMSEntry.getInstance(CachedSMSEntry.java:382)
        at com.sun.identity.sm.CachedSubEntries.<init>(CachedSubEntries.java:64)
        at com.sun.identity.sm.CachedSubEntries.getInstanceIfCached(CachedSubEntries.java:268)
        at com.sun.identity.sm.CachedSubEntries.getInstance(CachedSubEntries.java:276)
        at com.sun.identity.sm.ServiceManager.initialize(ServiceManager.java:1134)
        at com.sun.identity.sm.ServiceManager.isRealmEnabled(ServiceManager.java:865)
        at com.sun.identity.sm.ServiceManager.isCoexistenceMode(ServiceManager.java:829)
        at com.sun.identity.sm.ServiceSchemaManager.<init>(ServiceSchemaManager.java:77)
        at com.sun.identity.authentication.client.AuthClientUtils.getCookieDomains(AuthClientUtils.java:1371)
        at com.sun.identity.authentication.distUI.LoginViewBean.clearCookie(LoginViewBean.java:1766)
        at com.sun.identity.authentication.distUI.LoginViewBean.clearCookieAndDestroySession(LoginViewBean.java:1900)
        at com.sun.identity.authentication.distUI.LoginViewBean.processLogin(LoginViewBean.java:725)
        at com.sun.identity.authentication.distUI.LoginViewBean.forwardTo(LoginViewBean.java:439)
        at com.iplanet.jato.ApplicationServletBase.dispatchRequest(ApplicationServletBase.java:981)
        at com.iplanet.jato.ApplicationServletBase.processRequest(ApplicationServletBase.java:615)
        at com.iplanet.jato.ApplicationServletBase.doGet(ApplicationServletBase.java:459)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:718)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:831)
        at com.ibm.ws.cache.servlet.ServletWrapper.serviceProxied(ServletWrapper.java:307)
        at com.ibm.ws.cache.servlet.CacheHook.handleFragment(CacheHook.java:576)
        at com.ibm.ws.cache.servlet.CacheHook.handleServlet(CacheHook.java:250)
        at com.ibm.ws.cache.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:259)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1657)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1597)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:131)
        at com.sun.identity.distauth.setup.DistAuthConfiguratorFilter.doFilter(DistAuthConfiguratorFilter.java:101)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:188)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:116)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain._doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:77)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.doFilter(WebAppFilterManager.java:908)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:934)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:502)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapperImpl.handleRequest(ServletWrapperImpl.java:181)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.CacheServletWrapper.handleRequest(CacheServletWrapper.java:91)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java:864)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.handleRequest(WSWebContainer.java:1592)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.channel.WCChannelLink.ready(WCChannelLink.java:186)
        at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleDiscrimination(HttpInboundLink.java:452)
        at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleNewRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:511)
        at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.processRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:305)
        at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpICLReadCallback.complete(HttpICLReadCallback.java:83)
        at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.AioReadCompletionListener.futureCompleted(AioReadCompletionListener.java:165)
        at com.ibm.io.async.AbstractAsyncFuture.invokeCallback(AbstractAsyncFuture.java:217)
        at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncChannelFuture.fireCompletionActions(AsyncChannelFuture.java:161)
        at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncFuture.completed(AsyncFuture.java:138)
        at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.complete(ResultHandler.java:204)
        at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.runEventProcessingLoop(ResultHandler.java:775)
        at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler$2.run(ResultHandler.java:905)
        at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1646)
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you add 'login.example.com' to the DNS-alias of some realm?

You can enable 'debug' level tracing for 'DistAuth' by tweaking the setting in the bootstrap file for 'DistAuth'.

It will most likely show the root cause.

You may also have to look into OpenAM debug logs as well.

It seems you're using IBM WebSphere, if you're using IBM JDK as well you may have to apply special settings for IBM JCE.

Comment: Hi Bernhard, we make some tests, (change distauth version, change SSO version) and the problem is OpenAM 10.0.1 With WAS 7.0, back to SSO 10.0.0 and work fine. I'll test SSO 10.0.1 with WAS 8.0 and post results, thanks for help!